# ¿Como sumar solo los números de este arreglo de Strings?

Tags: java, array

Tengo la siguiente problemática en Java, tengo un arreglo de String el cual contiene números y cadenas, el problema pide verificar que es un número, en caso contrario decir que no es un número mediante consola y continuar recorriendo el arreglo. Al final el algoritmo debe indicar por consola la suma de los números.

Lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera

```
String[] arreglo = { "2", "CASA", "PRUEBA", "9", "-1" };

boolean esNumero = false;
int suma = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    if (arreglo[i].chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit)) {
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(arreglo[i]);
        suma += (temp);
     } else {
        System.out.println(arreglo[i] + " no es un número\n");
     }
}

System.out.println("La suma total de los números es = " + suma);
```

La salida arroja lo siguiente:

```
CASA no es un número

PRUEBA no es un número

-1 no es un número

La suma total de los números es = 11
```

El problema es que hay un número negativo en el arreglo, cómo puedo incluirlo como un número, no encuentro manera de validar que es un número negativo, ya que el resultado final debería arrojar 9. ¿Podrían ayudarme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías usar una expresión regular para comprobar si el elemento del vector es negativo, positivo u otra cosa, ya que `Character::isDigit` sólo identifica los números enteros.

Con esta expresión regular debería bastarte: `"-?[0-9]+.*[0-9]*"`.

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
String[] arreglo = { "2", "CASA", "PRUEBA", "9", "-1" };
int suma = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    if (arreglo[i].matches("-?[0-9]+.*[0-9]*")) {
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(arreglo[i]);
        suma += (temp);
    } else {
        System.out.println(arreglo[i] + " no es un número\n");
    }
}

System.out.println("La suma total de los números es = " + suma);
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] arreglo = { "2", "CASA", "PRUEBA", "9", "-1" };

boolean esNumero = false;
int suma = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    if(arreglo[i].charAt(0) == '-' && arreglo[i].substring(1).chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit)){
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(arreglo[i].substring(1));
        suma -= temp;
        continue;
    }

    if (arreglo[i].chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit)) {
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(arreglo[i]);
        suma += (temp);
    } else {
        System.out.println(arreglo[i] + " no es un número\n");
    }
}

System.out.println("La suma total de los números es = " + suma);
```

Añade la primera condicional